# Ramification divisors for normal varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a normal variety and $Y$ be  smooth variety with a dominant, generically finite, separable morphism,
$$
\pi: Y \longrightarrow X.
$$
It seems to be folklore that there is an effective Cartier divisor $R$ on $Y$ such that
$$
K_Y \sim \pi^* K_X + R.
$$
Can someone please explain in some detail why this is true? In the case that both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, then I believe we are able to obtain an inclusion $\pi^* K_X \subseteq K_Y  $ and proceed from there. But that doesn't work when $X$ is not smooth so the sheaf of differentials is no longer locally free. Is something able to explain how this ramification formula arises?

Comment: Do you need assistance with the case when $X,Y$ are both smooth? Or are you fine with that and just need help with the case where $X$ is normal but not necessarily smooth?

Comment: Hi @KReiser, I thought I could do the smooth case but I'm running into problems even there. For the simplest case of $\pi$ proper birational and $X, Y$ smooth my method would be to take the sequence for differentials $$ \pi^* \Omega_X \rightarrow \Omega_Y \rightarrow \Omega_{Y/X} \rightarrow 0$$ At the generic point by separability we have a surjective map of $K(Y)$-vector spaces of equal dimension so it is injective. Since the scheme is integral we get left exactness of the sequence of differentials. I would take the determinant of the sequence but $\Omega_{Y/X}$ may not even be locally free?

Comment: Are you sure about this? There are several issues, since $K_X$ is not a line bundle in general, $\pi^*K_X$ has to be treated carefully. My suspicion is that, in general (after dealing with the previous issue), you still may only have an $R$ which may or may not be effective.

Comment: You might want to read [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71950/higher-dimensional-version-of-the-hurwitz-formula) and see how much it helps. There's probably more work to do, but this should be a good starting point. (Apologies for not writing a real answer, but I am unfortunately a little too busy right now. Maybe I won't be soon!)